# Clear private data in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: internet-explorer, privacy, internet-explorer-6

All modern browsers have a feature to clear private data, but I can not find it in Internet Explorer 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Server 2003

- Tools > Internet Options... > General > Temporary Internet files

  - Delete Cookies > OK
  - Delete Files > Delete all offline content > OK
- Tools > Internet Options... > General > History > Clear History > Yes
- Tools > Internet Options... > Content > Personal information > AutoComplete... > Clear AutoComplete history

  - Clear Forms > OK
  - Clear Passwords > OK
- delete contents of C:\Documents and Settings(user)\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files

Comment: Then burn the whole thing down :). You should consider marking your answer as accepted, since it's the most complete one.

Comment: I have to give a colleague my virtual machine with all major browsers installed. Deleting personal data was easy with all browsers except IE6.

Comment: It's not that hard, even in IE6. It's awkward and involves a lot of steps, but it's there and it works.

Answer (score 5):

Go to the **Tools** menu and select **Internet Options...**

There, click on the **Delete Cookies**, **Delete Files** and **Clear Cache** buttons. That should do it.

Answer (score 3):

If you use an Internet Explorer 6 or earlier, you must use a privacy tool like [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/).

Internet Explorer 6 is not a modern browser by any means.

Comment: @Manni: Apparently not everybody likes it - I've just been downvoted.

Comment: -1 saying you *must* used a 3rd party tool.  While not always user friendly, the ability has existed natively well before IE6.  The question implies looking for a native solution.  Also the opinion on IE6 doesn't help.

Comment: @DHayes: You must if you want to get everything. Some cleanups can be done via IE, but not all.

Answer (score 1):

if you still have to use IE6, i recommend to install **[IE7Pro](http://www.ie7pro.com/)** which will add many features of a modern browser to IE6, including tabbed browsing and a **Privacy Cleaner** to clear typed addresses, auto-complete web forms, and passwords, cookies, history of visted sites, temporary internet files, you can also clear the Tab History and clear the Text Saver.

*IE7Pro is freeware and works with IE6, 7 and 8*